# Correct types for matrix size and looping variables

Tags: c++, for-loop, types

Have I chosen the correct types for the size and looping index in the below example. There seem to be so many options and `int` seems to appear in most scratch examples. What is canonical/best practice/correct types to use for my simple example. I have chosen `size_t` as it this represents the row/column matrix size and `ptrdiff_t` for the indexing as it involves pointer arithmetic.

```
template<size_t N, size_t P, size_t M>
void naive_multiply(T* A, T* B, T* C) {
    for(ptrdiff_t i=0; i!=N; ++i) {
        for(ptrdiff_t j=0; j!=M; ++j) {
            for(ptrdiff_t k=0; k!=P; ++k) {
                C[i + j*M] += A[i + k*P] * B[k + j*M];
            }
        }
    }
};
```

My only reservation with the above is the implicit type casting however, I may be ignorant in the sense that these are aliases of each other (if they are). I have also considered `uint_ptr_t` for the looping index.

Comment: Your container might have a typedef for "size_type" and "difference_type" or if you're just using raw arrays, that raises some run-time vs compile-time questions, but your current choices seem reasonable for those types. (opinion based)

Comment: Your indexing does not involve pointer arithmetic. At no point are you doing arithmetic on pointers, other than indexing itself, in the example code provided. And you certainly aren't doing pointer arithmetic that requires support for signed values. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: These are opinions, but they are primarily motivated by the intentions of the types mentioned.

`size_t` seems to be the right type to represent the number of elements in an array. After all, `size_t` is defined to be large enough to hold the size of any object, including any array. In fact, the return type for `sizeof()` is always  `size_t`.

It's a bit deceptive to use a `ptrdiff_t` for indexing unless you want to support negative indices (or if you're iterating over an array backwards and you want a negative index to be a stopping criterion; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971464/binary-search-in-data-structure-and-algorithm-analysis-in-c)), given that it is a signed type. That is why it's called `ptrdiff_t`; it was originally intended to represent the difference between two nearby pointers (which can be negative). In your example, none of your indexing variables should ever be negative. The sizes will also never be negative. Your arithmetic just involves computing sums and products of non-negative values, so the arithmetic outputs can also never be negative. Therefore, there is no reason to use a signed type like `ptrdiff_t`. `size_t` will suffice here as well; if it can represent the number of elements in an array, it can also represent any valid index in the array.

You probably don't want to use `uintptr_t` for the looping index. `uintptr_t` is designed for when you want to treat pointers like integers for performing integer-like operations. For instance, you might (for some strange reason) want to do bitwise arithmetic on a pointer, or you might (for some strange reason) want to intentionally misalign it. Cases like this are unusual; it's probably more common to use `uintptr_t` for obscuring the fact that it is a pointer entirely so that it can be treated more like a "handle" (e.g. to imply that the application shouldn't try to dereference it or delete it). Your indices aren't being treated like pointers at all (they're just being treated like indices which get multiplied by sizes); they're certainly not being treated like pointers that need to have integer-like arithmetic done on them.

**Conclusion:** Unless you'd like to support negative indexing for some reason, just use `size_t` for both the sizes and the indexing variables.

Comment: This is a great answer. One question, is ```size_t``` appropriate for indexing since an index is not technically the size of something but a location?

Comment: Cory Nelson gives a wonderful answer to that question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55604029/should-i-always-use-size-t-when-indexing-arrays#answer-55604267